# Symfony 2.7 - Changes to Views in shared hosting not working

Tags: symfony, shared-hosting

I'm working on a website developed on Symfony 2.7 and hosted on a shared host. It seems like views are served from Symfony cache created with `assetic` library. These cache files are not re-generated automatically after making changes to views. How do I apply changes in such scenario?

Comment: Are you talking about Twig templates? They are compiled and cached, when you make changes, you need to manually clear the cache in the production environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with a shared hosting. I had to connect to the server (ssh/ftp) and manually delete the cache folder generated for twig.

This cache folder in production mode and for that Symfony version is located at app/cache/prod/twig.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some changes, you should clear the cache by running this command:

php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod

Comment: Can't execute command line options in this shared hosting environment. Is cache:clear same as manually doing what @Samuel answered ?

Comment: The command is also doing a warmup (so it prepares the new cached files). Have you manually deleted the cache from prod folder and is still not working?